# Optimize My Sql

Tags: sql-server, epicorerp

I have a query in Epicor that I built using the BAQ Designer (which is just a gui for creating a SQL query). I recently made a change to add more data and now receive the following error.

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query.

I'm sure the monster I created is not optimal and I could probably make some changes to make it better. If any of the experts could take a look and help it would be greatly appreciated as I am not a SQL expert, just good enough to break stuff.The SQL is:

```
    With [Sales_Base] AS 
(select 
    [SalesRep].[SalesRepCode] as [SalesRep_SalesRepCode],
    [SalesRep].[Name] as [SalesRep_Name],
    [InvcHead].[InvoiceNum] as [InvcHead_InvoiceNum],
    [InvcHead].[InvoiceDate] as [InvcHead_InvoiceDate],
    [InvcHead].[PONum] as [InvcHead_PONum],
    [InvcDtl].[ExtPrice] as [InvcDtl_ExtPrice],
    [Customer].[CustID] as [Customer_CustID],
    [Customer].[Name] as [Customer_Name],
    [SalesCat].[Description] as [SalesCat_Description],
    [InvcDtl].[ProdCode] as [InvcDtl_ProdCode],
    [SalesRep].[RoleCode] as [SalesRep_RoleCode],
    [Customer].[GroupCode] as [Customer_GroupCode],
    (Constants.Today) as [Calculated_Today],
    (Constants.FirstDayOfMonth) as [Calculated_BOM],
    (case 
     when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) in (1,4,7,10) then Constants.FirstDayOfMonth
     when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) in (2,5,8,11) then DateAdd(month,-1,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
     else DateAdd(month,-2,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
 end) as [Calculated_BOQ],
    (case 
     when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 1 then Constants.FirstDayOfMonth
     when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 2 then DateAdd(month,-1,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 3 then DateAdd(month,-2,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 4 then DateAdd(month,-3,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 5 then DateAdd(month,-4,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 6 then DateAdd(month,-5,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 7 then DateAdd(month,-6,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 8 then DateAdd(month,-7,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 9 then DateAdd(month,-8,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 10 then DateAdd(month,-9,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
        when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 11 then DateAdd(month,-10,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
     else DateAdd(month,-11,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
 end) as [Calculated_BOY],
    [Customer5].[CustID] as [Customer5_CustID],
    [Customer5].[Name] as [Customer5_Name],
    [Customer5].[GroupCode] as [Customer5_GroupCode],
    [SalesRep].[EMailAddress] as [SalesRep_EMailAddress],
    [InvcDtl].[InvoiceLine] as [InvcDtl_InvoiceLine],
    (InvcDtl.ExtPrice + IsNull(InvcMisc.MiscAmt,0)) as [Calculated_InvcDtl_ExtPrice]
from Erp.SalesRep as SalesRep
left outer join Erp.InvcHead as InvcHead on 
    SalesRep.Company = InvcHead.Company
And
    SalesRep.SalesRepCode = [Ice].entry(1,SalesRepList,'~')
Or
    SalesRep.SalesRepCode = [Ice].entry(2,SalesRepList,'~')
Or
    SalesRep.SalesRepCode = [Ice].entry(3,SalesRepList,'~')
Or
    SalesRep.SalesRepCode = [Ice].entry(4,SalesRepList,'~')
Or
    SalesRep.SalesRepCode = [Ice].entry(5,SalesRepList,'~')
 and ( InvcHead.Posted = TRUE  and InvcHead.InvoiceType <> 'DEP'  )

left outer join Erp.InvcDtl as InvcDtl on 
    InvcHead.Company = InvcDtl.Company
And
    InvcHead.InvoiceNum = InvcDtl.InvoiceNum

left outer join Erp.Customer as Customer on 
    InvcHead.Company = Customer.Company
And
    InvcHead.SoldToCustNum = Customer.CustNum

left outer join Erp.SalesCat as SalesCat on 
    InvcDtl.Company = SalesCat.Company
And
    InvcDtl.SalesCatID = SalesCat.SalesCatID

left outer join Erp.Customer as Customer5 on 
    InvcDtl.Company = Customer5.Company
And
    InvcDtl.BTCustNum = Customer5.CustNum

left outer join Erp.InvcMisc as InvcMisc on 
    InvcDtl.Company = InvcMisc.Company
And
    InvcDtl.InvoiceNum = InvcMisc.InvoiceNum
And
    InvcDtl.InvoiceLine = InvcMisc.InvoiceLine
 and ( InvcMisc.MiscCode = 'exp'  )

 where (SalesRep.RoleCode in ('sales', 'salesden', 'salesflx', 'salesmed', 'salespm')  and SalesRep.SalesRepCode <> 'default'  and SalesRep.SalesRepCode <> 'national'  and SalesRep.SalesRepCode <> 'house'  and SalesRep.SalesRepCode <> 'flexi'  and SalesRep.SalesRepCode <> 'prescale'  and SalesRep.InActive = FALSE))
 ,[Sales_Base_Add_MR] AS 
(select 
    (Sales_Base5.SalesRep_SalesRepCode) as [Calculated_A_SalesRepCode],
    (Sales_Base5.SalesRep_Name) as [Calculated_A_SalesRepName],
    (Sales_Base5.InvcHead_InvoiceNum) as [Calculated_A_InvoiceNum],
    (Sales_Base5.InvcHead_InvoiceDate) as [Calculated_A_InvoiceDate],
    (Sales_Base5.InvcHead_PONum) as [Calculated_A_PONum],
    (Sales_Base5.Calculated_InvcDtl_ExtPrice) as [Calculated_A_ExtPrice],
    (Sales_Base5.Customer_CustID) as [Calculated_A_CustID],
    (Sales_Base5.Customer_Name) as [Calculated_A_Cust],
    (Sales_Base5.SalesCat_Description) as [Calculated_A_SalesCat],
    (Sales_Base5.InvcDtl_ProdCode) as [Calculated_A_ProdCode],
    (Sales_Base5.SalesRep_RoleCode) as [Calculated_A_RoleCode],
    (Sales_Base5.Customer_GroupCode) as [Calculated_A_GroupCode],
    (Sales_Base5.Calculated_Today) as [Calculated_A_Today],
    (Sales_Base5.Calculated_BOM) as [Calculated_A_BOM],
    (Sales_Base5.Calculated_BOQ) as [Calculated_A_BOQ],
    (Sales_Base5.Calculated_BOY) as [Calculated_A_BOY],
    (Sales_Base5.Customer5_CustID) as [Calculated_A_BTCustID],
    (Sales_Base5.Customer5_Name) as [Calculated_A_BTCust],
    (Sales_Base5.Customer5_GroupCode) as [Calculated_A_BTGroupCode],
    [SalesRep2].[SalesRepCode] as [SalesRep2_SalesRepCode],
    [SalesRep2].[Name] as [SalesRep2_Name],
    [SalesRep2].[RoleCode] as [SalesRep2_RoleCode],
    (Sales_Base5.SalesRep_EMailAddress) as [Calculated_A_Email],
    (Sales_Base5.InvcDtl_InvoiceLine) as [Calculated_A_Line]
from  Sales_Base  as Sales_Base5
left outer join Erp.InvcHead as InvcHead1 on 
    Sales_Base5.InvcHead_InvoiceNum = InvcHead1.InvoiceNum

left outer join Erp.SalesRep as SalesRep2 on 
    InvcHead1.Company = SalesRep2.Company
And
    [Ice].entry(1,SalesRepList,'~') = SalesRep2.SalesRepCode
Or
    [Ice].entry(2,SalesRepList,'~') = SalesRep2.SalesRepCode
Or
    [Ice].entry(3,SalesRepList,'~') = SalesRep2.SalesRepCode
Or
    [Ice].entry(4,SalesRepList,'~') = SalesRep2.SalesRepCode
Or
    [Ice].entry(5,SalesRepList,'~') = SalesRep2.SalesRepCode
 and ( SalesRep2.RoleCode = 'mfgrep'  )

 where (Sales_Base5.Calculated_InvcDtl_ExtPrice <> 0  and Sales_Base5.InvcDtl_ProdCode <> ''))
 ,[Total] AS 
(select 
    [Sales_Base_Add_MR3].[Calculated_A_InvoiceNum] as [Calculated_A_InvoiceNum],
    (sum( Sales_Base_Add_MR3.Calculated_A_ExtPrice )) as [Calculated_Invoice_Total]
from  Sales_Base_Add_MR  as Sales_Base_Add_MR3
group by [Sales_Base_Add_MR3].[Calculated_A_InvoiceNum])
 ,[Key1] AS 
(select 
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR.Calculated_A_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Key1_SR],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR.Calculated_A_SalesRepName + Sales_Base_Add_MR.SalesRep2_Name) as [Calculated_Key1_Key]
from  Sales_Base_Add_MR  as Sales_Base_Add_MR
 where (Sales_Base_Add_MR.SalesRep2_RoleCode = 'mfgrep')
group by (Sales_Base_Add_MR.Calculated_A_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Key1_SR],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR.Calculated_A_SalesRepName + Sales_Base_Add_MR.SalesRep2_Name) as [Calculated_Key1_Key])
 ,[Key2] AS 
(select 
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR2.Calculated_A_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Key2_SR],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR2.Calculated_A_SalesRepName + Sales_Base_Add_MR2.Calculated_A_BTCustID) as [Calculated_Key2_Key]
from  Sales_Base_Add_MR  as Sales_Base_Add_MR2
 where (Sales_Base_Add_MR2.Calculated_A_BTGroupCode in ('dend', 'flxd', 'medd', 'prsd'))
group by (Sales_Base_Add_MR2.Calculated_A_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Key2_SR],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR2.Calculated_A_SalesRepName + Sales_Base_Add_MR2.Calculated_A_BTCustID) as [Calculated_Key2_Key])
 ,[B] AS 
(select 
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_SalesRepCode) as [Calculated_B_SalesRepCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_B_SalesRepName],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_InvoiceNum) as [Calculated_B_InvoiceNum],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_InvoiceDate) as [Calculated_B_InvoiceDate],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_PONum) as [Calculated_B_PONum],
    (Total.Calculated_Invoice_Total) as [Calculated_B_OrderTotal],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_CustID) as [Calculated_B_CustID],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_Cust) as [Calculated_B_Cust],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_RoleCode) as [Calculated_B_RoleCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_GroupCode) as [Calculated_B_GroupCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_Today) as [Calculated_B_Today],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BOM) as [Calculated_B_BOM],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BOQ) as [Calculated_B_BOQ],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BOY) as [Calculated_B_BOY],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BTCustID) as [Calculated_B_BTCustID],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BTCust) as [Calculated_B_BTCust],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BTGroupCode) as [Calculated_B_BTGroupCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.SalesRep2_SalesRepCode) as [Calculated_B_MRCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.SalesRep2_Name) as [Calculated_B_MRName],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.SalesRep2_RoleCode) as [Calculated_B_MRRoleCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_Email) as [Calculated_B_Email],
    (Key1.Calculated_Key1_Key) as [Calculated_B_Key],
    (Key2.Calculated_Key2_Key) as [Calculated_B_Key2]
from  Sales_Base_Add_MR  as Sales_Base_Add_MR14
left outer join  Key1  as Key1 on 
    Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_SalesRepName = Key1.Calculated_Key1_SR
And
    Calculated_A_SalesRepName + SalesRep2_Name = Key1.Calculated_Key1_Key

left outer join  Key2  as Key2 on 
    Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_SalesRepName = Key2.Calculated_Key2_SR
And
    Calculated_A_SalesRepName + Calculated_A_BTCustID = Key2.Calculated_Key2_Key

left outer join  Total  as Total on 
    Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_InvoiceNum = Total.Calculated_A_InvoiceNum

group by (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_SalesRepCode) as [Calculated_B_SalesRepCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_B_SalesRepName],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_InvoiceNum) as [Calculated_B_InvoiceNum],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_InvoiceDate) as [Calculated_B_InvoiceDate],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_PONum) as [Calculated_B_PONum],
    (Total.Calculated_Invoice_Total) as [Calculated_B_OrderTotal],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_CustID) as [Calculated_B_CustID],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_Cust) as [Calculated_B_Cust],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_RoleCode) as [Calculated_B_RoleCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_GroupCode) as [Calculated_B_GroupCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_Today) as [Calculated_B_Today],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BOM) as [Calculated_B_BOM],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BOQ) as [Calculated_B_BOQ],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BOY) as [Calculated_B_BOY],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BTCustID) as [Calculated_B_BTCustID],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BTCust) as [Calculated_B_BTCust],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_BTGroupCode) as [Calculated_B_BTGroupCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.SalesRep2_SalesRepCode) as [Calculated_B_MRCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.SalesRep2_Name) as [Calculated_B_MRName],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.SalesRep2_RoleCode) as [Calculated_B_MRRoleCode],
    (Sales_Base_Add_MR14.Calculated_A_Email) as [Calculated_B_Email],
    (Key1.Calculated_Key1_Key) as [Calculated_B_Key],
    (Key2.Calculated_Key2_Key) as [Calculated_B_Key2])
 ,[Sales_BOM] AS 
(select 
    (B1.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_BOM_Rep],
    (sum( B1.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_Sales_BOM_Sum]
from  B  as B1
 where (B1.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B1.Calculated_B_BOM  and B1.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B1.Calculated_B_Today)
group by (B1.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_BOM_Rep])
 ,[Sales_BOQ] AS 
(select 
    (B2.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Rep],
    (sum( B2.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Sum]
from  B  as B2
 where (B2.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B2.Calculated_B_BOQ  and B2.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B2.Calculated_B_Today)
group by (B2.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Rep])
 ,[Sales_BOY] AS 
(select 
    (B3.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_BOY_Rep],
    (sum( B3.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_Sales_BOY_Sum]
from  B  as B3
 where (B3.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B3.Calculated_B_BOY  and B3.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B3.Calculated_B_Today)
group by (B3.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_BOY_Rep])
 ,[MR_BOM] AS 
(select 
    (sum( B5.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_MR_BOM_Sum],
    (B5.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_BOM_Key]
from  B  as B5
 where (B5.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B5.Calculated_B_BOM  and B5.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B5.Calculated_B_Today  and B5.Calculated_B_MRRoleCode = 'mfgrep')
group by (B5.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_BOM_Key])
 ,[MR_BOQ] AS 
(select 
    (sum( B6.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_MR_BOQ_Sum],
    (B6.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_BOQ_Key]
from  B  as B6
 where (B6.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B6.Calculated_B_BOQ  and B6.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B6.Calculated_B_Today  and B6.Calculated_B_MRRoleCode = 'mfgrep')
group by (B6.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_BOQ_Key])
 ,[MR_BOY] AS 
(select 
    (sum( B7.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_MR_BOY_Sum],
    (B7.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_BOY_Key],
    (B7.Calculated_B_MRName) as [Calculated_MR_BOY_MR]
from  B  as B7
 where (B7.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B7.Calculated_B_BOY  and B7.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B7.Calculated_B_Today  and B7.Calculated_B_MRRoleCode = 'mfgrep')
group by (B7.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_BOY_Key],
    (B7.Calculated_B_MRName) as [Calculated_MR_BOY_MR])
 ,[Dist_BOM] AS 
(select 
    (sum( B9.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_Dist_BOM_Sum],
    (B9.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_BOM_Key]
from  B  as B9
 where (B9.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B9.Calculated_B_BOM  and B9.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B9.Calculated_B_Today  and B9.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode in ('dend', 'flxd', 'medd', 'prsd'))
group by (B9.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_BOM_Key])
 ,[Dist_BOQ] AS 
(select 
    (sum( B10.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_Dist_BOQ_Sum],
    (B10.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_BOQ_Key]
from  B  as B10
 where (B10.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B10.Calculated_B_BOQ  and B10.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B10.Calculated_B_Today  and B10.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode in ('dend', 'flxd', 'medd', 'prsd'))
group by (B10.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_BOQ_Key])
 ,[Dist_BOY] AS 
(select 
    (sum( B11.Calculated_B_OrderTotal )) as [Calculated_Dist_BOY_Sum],
    (B11.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_BOY_Key],
    (B11.Calculated_B_BTCustID) as [Calculated_Dist_BOY_ID],
    (B11.Calculated_B_BTCust) as [Calculated_Dist_BOYDist],
    (B11.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode) as [Calculated_Dist_BOY_Group]
from  B  as B11
 where (B11.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B11.Calculated_B_BOY  and B11.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B11.Calculated_B_Today  and B11.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode in ('dend', 'flxd', 'medd', 'prsd'))
group by (B11.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_BOY_Key],
    (B11.Calculated_B_BTCustID) as [Calculated_Dist_BOY_ID],
    (B11.Calculated_B_BTCust) as [Calculated_Dist_BOYDist],
    (B11.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode) as [Calculated_Dist_BOY_Group])
 ,[Sales_Group] AS 
(select 
    (B12.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_Group_SR],
    (B12.Calculated_B_Email) as [Calculated_Sales_Group_Email]
from  B  as B12
group by (B12.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Sales_Group_SR],
    (B12.Calculated_B_Email) as [Calculated_Sales_Group_Email])
 ,[MR_Group] AS 
(select 
    (B13.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_MR_Group_SR],
    (B13.Calculated_B_Email) as [Calculated_MR_Group_Email],
    (B13.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_Group_Key]
from  B  as B13
 where (B13.Calculated_B_Key is not null)
group by (B13.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_MR_Group_SR],
    (B13.Calculated_B_Email) as [Calculated_MR_Group_Email],
    (B13.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_MR_Group_Key])
 ,[Dist_Group] AS 
(select 
    (B15.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Dist_Group_SR],
    (B15.Calculated_B_Email) as [Calculated_Dist_Group_Email],
    (B15.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_Group_Key]
from  B  as B15
 where (B15.Calculated_B_Key2 is not null)
group by (B15.Calculated_B_SalesRepName) as [Calculated_Dist_Group_SR],
    (B15.Calculated_B_Email) as [Calculated_Dist_Group_Email],
    (B15.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_Dist_Group_Key])
 ,[Report] AS 
(select 
    (IsNull(B16.Calculated_B_SalesRepCode,'Sales')) as [Calculated_R_SalesRepCode],
    (Sales_Group.Calculated_Sales_Group_SR) as [Calculated_R_SalesRepName],
    (IsNull(B16.Calculated_B_InvoiceNum,9999999)) as [Calculated_R_InvoiceNum],
    (IsNull(B16.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate, convert(date, '30991231', 112))) as [Calculated_R_InvoiceDate],
    (B16.Calculated_B_PONum) as [Calculated_R_PONum],
    (B16.Calculated_B_OrderTotal) as [Calculated_R_InvoiceTotal],
    (B16.Calculated_B_CustID) as [Calculated_R_CustID],
    (B16.Calculated_B_Cust) as [Calculated_R_Cust],
    (B16.Calculated_B_RoleCode) as [Calculated_R_RoleCode],
    (B16.Calculated_B_GroupCode) as [Calculated_R_GroupCode],
    (B16.Calculated_B_BTCustID) as [Calculated_R_BTCustID],
    (B16.Calculated_B_BTCust) as [Calculated_R_BTCust],
    (B16.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode) as [Calculated_R_BTGroupCode],
    (B16.Calculated_B_MRCode) as [Calculated_R_MRCode],
    (B16.Calculated_B_MRName) as [Calculated_R_MRName],
    (B16.Calculated_B_MRRoleCode) as [Calculated_R_MRRoleCode],
    (Sales_Group.Calculated_Sales_Group_Email) as [Calculated_R_Email],
    (B16.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_R_Key],
    (B16.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_R_Key2],
    (Sales_BOM.Calculated_Sales_BOM_Sum) as [Calculated_R_SalesBOM],
    (Sales_BOQ.Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Sum) as [Calculated_R_SalesBOQ],
    (Sales_BOY.Calculated_Sales_BOY_Sum) as [Calculated_R_SalesBOY],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_R_MRBOM],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_R_MRBOQ],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_R_MRBOY],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_R_DistBOM],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_R_DistBOQ],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_R_DistBOY]
from  Sales_Group  as Sales_Group
left outer join  B  as B16 on 
    Sales_Group.Calculated_Sales_Group_SR = B16.Calculated_B_SalesRepName
 and ( B16.Calculated_B_Key is null and B16.Calculated_B_Key2 is null and B16.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B16.Calculated_B_BOM  and B16.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B16.Calculated_B_Today  )

left outer join  Sales_BOM  as Sales_BOM on 
    Sales_Group.Calculated_Sales_Group_SR = Sales_BOM.Calculated_Sales_BOM_Rep

left outer join  Sales_BOQ  as Sales_BOQ on 
    Sales_Group.Calculated_Sales_Group_SR = Sales_BOQ.Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Rep

left outer join  Sales_BOY  as Sales_BOY on 
    Sales_Group.Calculated_Sales_Group_SR = Sales_BOY.Calculated_Sales_BOY_Rep

UNION
select 
    (B17.Calculated_B_SalesRepCode) as [Calculated_C_1],
    (MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_SR) as [Calculated_C_2],
    (B17.Calculated_B_InvoiceNum) as [Calculated_C_3],
    (B17.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate) as [Calculated_C_4],
    (B17.Calculated_B_PONum) as [Calculated_C_5],
    (B17.Calculated_B_OrderTotal) as [Calculated_C_6],
    (B17.Calculated_B_CustID) as [Calculated_C_9],
    (B17.Calculated_B_Cust) as [Calculated_C_10],
    (B17.Calculated_B_RoleCode) as [Calculated_C_13],
    (B17.Calculated_B_GroupCode) as [Calculated_C_14],
    (B17.Calculated_B_BTCustID) as [Calculated_C_15],
    (B17.Calculated_B_BTCust) as [Calculated_C_16],
    (B17.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode) as [Calculated_C_17],
    (B17.Calculated_B_MRCode) as [Calculated_C_20],
    (IsNull(B17.Calculated_B_MRName,MR_BOY.Calculated_MR_BOY_MR)) as [Calculated_C_21],
    (B17.Calculated_B_MRRoleCode) as [Calculated_C_22],
    (MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_Email) as [Calculated_C_23],
    (MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_Key) as [Calculated_C_24],
    (B17.Calculated_B_Key2) as [Calculated_C_25],
    (Sales_BOM2.Calculated_Sales_BOM_Sum) as [Calculated_C_27],
    (Sales_BOQ2.Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Sum) as [Calculated_C_28],
    (Sales_BOY2.Calculated_Sales_BOY_Sum) as [Calculated_C_29],
    (MR_BOM.Calculated_MR_BOM_Sum) as [Calculated_C_31],
    (MR_BOQ.Calculated_MR_BOQ_Sum) as [Calculated_C_32],
    (MR_BOY.Calculated_MR_BOY_Sum) as [Calculated_C_33],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_C_35],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_C_36],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_C_37]
from  MR_Group  as MR_Group
left outer join  B  as B17 on 
    MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_Key = B17.Calculated_B_Key
 and ( B17.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B17.Calculated_B_BOM  and B17.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B17.Calculated_B_Today  )

left outer join  MR_BOM  as MR_BOM on 
    MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_Key = MR_BOM.Calculated_MR_BOM_Key

left outer join  MR_BOQ  as MR_BOQ on 
    MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_Key = MR_BOQ.Calculated_MR_BOQ_Key

left outer join  MR_BOY  as MR_BOY on 
    MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_Key = MR_BOY.Calculated_MR_BOY_Key

left outer join  Sales_BOM  as Sales_BOM2 on 
    MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_SR = Sales_BOM2.Calculated_Sales_BOM_Rep

left outer join  Sales_BOQ  as Sales_BOQ2 on 
    MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_SR = Sales_BOQ2.Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Rep

left outer join  Sales_BOY  as Sales_BOY2 on 
    MR_Group.Calculated_MR_Group_SR = Sales_BOY2.Calculated_Sales_BOY_Rep

UNION
select 
    (B18.Calculated_B_SalesRepCode) as [Calculated_D_1],
    (Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_SR) as [Calculated_D_2],
    (B18.Calculated_B_InvoiceNum) as [Calculated_D_3],
    (B18.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate) as [Calculated_D_4],
    (B18.Calculated_B_PONum) as [Calculated_D_5],
    (B18.Calculated_B_OrderTotal) as [Calculated_D_6],
    (B18.Calculated_B_CustID) as [Calculated_D_9],
    (B18.Calculated_B_Cust) as [Calculated_D_10],
    (B18.Calculated_B_RoleCode) as [Calculated_D_13],
    (B18.Calculated_B_GroupCode) as [Calculated_D_14],
    (IsNull(B18.Calculated_B_BTCustID,Dist_BOY.Calculated_Dist_BOY_ID)) as [Calculated_D_15],
    (IsNull(B18.Calculated_B_BTCust,Dist_BOY.Calculated_Dist_BOYDist)) as [Calculated_D_16],
    (IsNull(B18.Calculated_B_BTGroupCode,Dist_BOY.Calculated_Dist_BOY_Group)) as [Calculated_D_17],
    (B18.Calculated_B_MRCode) as [Calculated_D_20],
    (B18.Calculated_B_MRName) as [Calculated_D_21],
    (B18.Calculated_B_MRRoleCode) as [Calculated_D_22],
    (Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_Email) as [Calculated_D_23],
    (B18.Calculated_B_Key) as [Calculated_D_24],
    (Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_Key) as [Calculated_D_25],
    (Sales_BOM1.Calculated_Sales_BOM_Sum) as [Calculated_D_27],
    (Sales_BOQ1.Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Sum) as [Calculated_D_28],
    (Sales_BOY1.Calculated_Sales_BOY_Sum) as [Calculated_D_29],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_D_31],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_D_32],
    (NULL) as [Calculated_D_33],
    (Dist_BOM.Calculated_Dist_BOM_Sum) as [Calculated_D_35],
    (Dist_BOQ.Calculated_Dist_BOQ_Sum) as [Calculated_D_36],
    (Dist_BOY.Calculated_Dist_BOY_Sum) as [Calculated_D_37]
from  Dist_Group  as Dist_Group
left outer join  B  as B18 on 
    Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_Key = B18.Calculated_B_Key2
 and ( B18.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate >= B18.Calculated_B_BOM  and B18.Calculated_B_InvoiceDate <= B18.Calculated_B_Today  )

left outer join  Dist_BOM  as Dist_BOM on 
    Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_Key = Dist_BOM.Calculated_Dist_BOM_Key

left outer join  Dist_BOQ  as Dist_BOQ on 
    Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_Key = Dist_BOQ.Calculated_Dist_BOQ_Key

left outer join  Dist_BOY  as Dist_BOY on 
    Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_Key = Dist_BOY.Calculated_Dist_BOY_Key

left outer join  Sales_BOM  as Sales_BOM1 on 
    Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_SR = Sales_BOM1.Calculated_Sales_BOM_Rep

left outer join  Sales_BOQ  as Sales_BOQ1 on 
    Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_SR = Sales_BOQ1.Calculated_Sales_BOQ_Rep

left outer join  Sales_BOY  as Sales_BOY1 on 
    Dist_Group.Calculated_Dist_Group_SR = Sales_BOY1.Calculated_Sales_BOY_Rep)

select 
    [Report].[Calculated_R_SalesRepCode] as [Calculated_R_SalesRepCode],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_SalesRepName] as [Calculated_R_SalesRepName],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_InvoiceNum] as [Calculated_R_InvoiceNum],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_InvoiceDate] as [Calculated_R_InvoiceDate],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_PONum] as [Calculated_R_PONum],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_InvoiceTotal] as [Calculated_R_InvoiceTotal],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_CustID] as [Calculated_R_CustID],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_Cust] as [Calculated_R_Cust],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_RoleCode] as [Calculated_R_RoleCode],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_GroupCode] as [Calculated_R_GroupCode],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_BTCustID] as [Calculated_R_BTCustID],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_BTCust] as [Calculated_R_BTCust],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_BTGroupCode] as [Calculated_R_BTGroupCode],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_MRCode] as [Calculated_R_MRCode],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_MRName] as [Calculated_R_MRName],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_MRRoleCode] as [Calculated_R_MRRoleCode],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_Email] as [Calculated_R_Email],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_Key] as [Calculated_R_Key],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_Key2] as [Calculated_R_Key2],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_SalesBOM] as [Calculated_R_SalesBOM],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_SalesBOQ] as [Calculated_R_SalesBOQ],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_SalesBOY] as [Calculated_R_SalesBOY],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_MRBOM] as [Calculated_R_MRBOM],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_MRBOQ] as [Calculated_R_MRBOQ],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_MRBOY] as [Calculated_R_MRBOY],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_DistBOM] as [Calculated_R_DistBOM],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_DistBOQ] as [Calculated_R_DistBOQ],
    [Report].[Calculated_R_DistBOY] as [Calculated_R_DistBOY]
from  Report  as Report
```

Comment: `Please simplify the query` ... this is sound advice.  I think your query is too long to get a meaningful answer here.

Comment: This is a monster query! split it and find out what causing the performance issues. Only then we'll be able to help.

Comment: It almost looks like you are trying to perform an entire ETL process in a single query. Break the query apart, use views and just *simplify it*. If you end up combining 10 different queries in a `SELECT (hugequery1), (hugequery2)` etc, you are doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

a) Look for simplifying parts of the query. For example, this part can be vastly simplified:

```
(case 
 when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 1 then Constants.FirstDayOfMonth
 when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 2 then DateAdd(month,-1,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 3 then DateAdd(month,-2,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 4 then DateAdd(month,-3,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 5 then DateAdd(month,-4,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 6 then DateAdd(month,-5,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 7 then DateAdd(month,-6,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 8 then DateAdd(month,-7,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 9 then DateAdd(month,-8,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 10 then DateAdd(month,-9,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
    when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 11 then DateAdd(month,-10,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
 else DateAdd(month,-11,Constants.FirstDayOfMonth)
 end) as [Calculated_BOY],
```

Could be instead

```
(case 
 when DatePart(month,Constants.Today) = 12 then Constants.FirstDayOfMonth
 else DateAdd(month, - ( DatePart(month,Constants.Today) - 1), Constants.FirstDayOfMonth) end ) as [Calculated_BOY]
```

b) Separate the subselects into temporary tables, particularly those that you can verify produce relatively small resultsets (let's say thousand of rows or less). Providing those temporary tables to the select instead of subselects will help the query processor

Comment: thank you! I updated my query with your suggestion and will look through the rest to try and simplify. Like I said, I'm good enough to break stuff and never would have saw this without your help.

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder what is

```
[Ice].entry(1,SalesRepList,'~')
```

if it is a function, you can work on it.
But it seems to be creating constant values, not dynamic per row

I see that the query is formed of multiple CTE expressions

The Report CTE is formed of UNIONs can be converted to UNION ALLs if possible

And many GROUP By for calculations
Perhaps those can be converted to new aggregation syntax with SUM() function using PARTITION BY clause

Comment: thank you! I changed all but one of the Unions to Union All.